# jsvc 1.0.15 installation on CentOS 6.x

Tags: java, apache, centos, centos6, jsvc

After some google search, it seems that I can only install apache jsvc jsvc-1.0.1-8.9.el6 on CentOS 6.x. It's the latest version for CentOS. See from:

http://pkgs.org/search/?query=jsvc&type=smart

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=jsvc

However jsvc 1.0.1 doesn't support some stardard JVM args such as "-javaagent" which I'm currently depend on. How can I install an newer version, e.g.the latest 1.0.15 on my CentoS instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way,may be the only way, is to build jsvc binary from source. I created  a cookbook for it on github: https://github.com/wangjunbo924/jsvc-chef.

see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing a more recent version using the package manager:

```
sudo yum install jsvc
```